# Cocos 2d Expression Error

Tags: compiler-errors, cocos2d-iphone, syntax-error, c-preprocessor

I am trying to detect which iPhone the app is running on by running the code below, but I get an Expected expression error

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

Then i am using these for usage:

```
if(IS_IPAD)
{
    NSLog(@"IS_IPAD");
}
if(IS_IPHONE)
{
    NSLog(@"IS_IPHONE");
}
if(IS_RETINA)
{
    NSLog(@"IS_RETINA");
}
if(IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS)
{
    NSLog(@"IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS");
}
if(IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    NSLog(@"IS_IPHONE_5");
}
if(IS_IPHONE_6)
{
    NSLog(@"IS_IPHONE_6");
}
if(IS_IPHONE_6P)
{
    NSLog(@"IS_IPHONE_6P");
}
```

Then here is the code:

```
bool MainScene::init()
    {



    if ( !CCLayer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    MyGameBridge::showBanner();


    g_nScore = 0;



    r =  72;
    g =  180;
    b =  187;
    CCLayerColor *background = CCLayerColor::create(ccc4(r, g, b, 255), G_SWIDTH, G_SHEIGHT);
    this->addChild(background, 0);




    newSprite("ground", G_SWIDTH/2, G_SHEIGHT / 2, this, 2, RATIO_XY);

    newSprite("Player", G_SWIDTH/2, getY(855), this, 0, RATIO_X);

    //    newSprite(CCString::createWithFormat("bg_main%d_en", graphics_mode)->getCString(), G_SWIDTH/2, G_SHEIGHT/2, this, 0, RATIO_XY);

    CCMenuItemToggle* btnSound=newToggleButton("sound", G_SWIDTH/2 - getX(150), getY(650), this, menu_selector(MainScene::onClickSound), true, RATIO_X);
    btnSound->setSelectedIndex(g_bSound?0:1);
    CCMenuItemImage *scoreItem=newButton(CCString::createWithFormat("btn_score")->getCString(), G_SWIDTH/2 + getX(150), getY(650), this, menu_selector(MainScene::onClickScore), true, RATIO_X);
    scoreItem->setScale(G_SCALEX*0.95);
     //    scoreItem->setScaleY(G_SCALEY*0.9);


    // sets the postion, and image of the play button

    CCMenu* menu;
    menu = CCMenu::create(
                          newButton(CCString::createWithFormat("Play")->getCString(), G_SWIDTH/2, getY(500), this, menu_selector(MainScene::onClickPlay), true, RATIO_X),

                          scoreItem,

                          btnSound,

                          NULL);

    menu->setPosition(0, 0);
    this->addChild(menu);


    if(IS_IPHONE_6P) // Here is where the expression error occurs
    {
        NSLog(@"IS_IPHONE_6P");
    }



    //adds the title

    newLabel(CCString::createWithFormat("Pop Up!")->getCString(), CCString::createWithFormat("DINAlternate-Bold")->getCString(), 200, G_SWIDTH / 2, getY(150), this, 2, RATIO_Y);

    // adds the highscore title

    newLabel(CCString::createWithFormat("Best: %d", g_nBestScore)->getCString(), CCString::createWithFormat("Arial")->getCString(), 85, G_SWIDTH / 2, getY(270), this, 2, RATIO_Y);




    return true;



}
```

What do I need to fix/edit?

Comment: exact error message, please... on which line?

Comment: i get the error: Parse Issue, Expected expression. On this line of code...                if(IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        NSLog(@"IS_IPHONE_6P");
        
        
        
  
    }

Comment: your code (#defines + if) compiles perfectly in my case. would you try commenting the `if` out and check whether the error is still there? would you try using `IS_IPAD` instead of `IS_IPHONE_6P` and check again?

Comment: I have tried both of your solutions, none of them worked. I actually get three errors:     1. Semantic Issue use of undeclared indentifier 'UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM'     2. Semantic Issue use of undeclared indentifier 'UIUserinterfaceidiomiPhone'    3. Parse issue, Expected identifier